# Using pointer and referencing functions

Tags: c

Pretty new to programming so please bear with me,
I am trying to create a code which prompts the user to enter a size for an array, then using pointers call a function to get all even numbers up to the entered integer, I don't know what to do from here Here is what I have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100
int *getEvenNumbers();
main()
{
    int *ptr,N;

    printf("Please enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    SIZE=N;
     int even[SIZE];


    ptr=getEvenNumbers();
    printf("%d",*ptr);

}
int *getEvenNumbers(int *even)
{
    int point=0;
    for(point=1;point<=SIZE;point++)

    if(point%2==0)

    //point = 12;
    return (&point);
}
```

Comment: It is undefined behaviour to return a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: Declare `int *getEvenNumbers(int *even);` before `main()` to get the compiler to point out one error — you don't pass `even` to the function.  Inside the function, you return on the first even value of `point` (which is 2) and never set anything in the array.  And you return a pointer to a local variable, which is a strict no-no; it leads to undefined behaviour when it is used by the calling code.

Comment: Well, your task is to fill the array `even` with numbers, and to pay attention that this array doesn't overflow. What you do is to return a pointer to an automatic variable, which is illegal. Also, how does your function know the upper limit? How does it know the maximum size of the array?

Comment: Do you want to save to the variable you pass a pointer to or do you just want to pass a pointer to an array of numbers?

Comment: You cannot do `SIZE=N;`, because `SIZE` is  not a variable. It is an integer literal. What does `100 = x`even mean? Breaking the natural numbers?

Comment: And you should also declare `int main()`.

Comment: You guys are all incredibly helpful, I apologize if the question sounded scattered/uneducated, but that's just because my knowledge is so limited

Answer (score 0):

At the C language, arrays size must be const.
Unlike java or C#, you cannot have an array at the size of 10, and then while the program is running change it to 15.
Therefore, the size of an array must be a const number (or a define, which is basicly the same thing).
As well, a define is something that cannot be changed like a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out multiple violations in your code.

1. You are using main() which is not the right prototype for main() it should be

   `int main()`
2. Next in your function getEvenNumbers() you are trying to return local variable's address so you should be getting below warning.

   `warning: function returns address of local variable`
3. `SIZE` is a integer literal so you when you do `SIZE =n;` you should be getting the below error.

   `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`
4. The function call `ptr=getEvenNumbers();` is wrong it needs one argurment.